# Creating first PHP CLI, getting started

Tags: php, magento

Hello I would like to create a simple PHP CLI to do some scaffolding. For a new project I am working on, we are using Magento to build an eCommerce store. Magento to comes with many default modules, but  you can also create your own and we will have to be creating many custom modules.

I would like to create a simple PHP CLI which can be run to generate a default file path/structure for a module. It would be passed in something like the module name and maybe even path of the application and then generate the template folders and files.

I am new to PHP development, so i think this will be a simple enough project and a good learning experience. However I am having trouble knowing where to start. The end goal would probably be to have it archived in a .phar file that can just be run on the command line.

Any suggestions on how I can get started with this?

Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have any experience in Java the idea is the same but you run the code with `php` instead of `java` . The major difference is that code in PHP which isn't in a class will just run off the bat (which is kind of the way to make a "main" method).

Answer (score 0):

No reason you can't.  PHP in the command line reads the $argv array from the command line.

Here's one of my CLI apps; perhaps it can be instructive:   https://github.com/dalecosp/NixArchive/blob/master/archive